# what is the best strategy to handle messages between UI code (Activities) and business logic code

Tags: java, android

I'm looking the best way to Implement the messages and notifications between activities and the business logic code, I used listeners but I had to register and unregister to avoid that activity do any thing while it is not active.have any body use better strategy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this link:

[Android Threads, Handlers and AsyncTask - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Two ways to do this in Android

1. Handler
2. AsyncTask

Comment: I'm new to the concept of handler i wish if I can find some more details of how to use them